# Check two values in array

Tags: matlab

I have an array in Matlab called `myVec` and I have to execute an operation if the array contains at least one 1 and one 0.
I do not know how I could do that, I tried with `find` but it did not work.
This is what I need.

```
if %myVec contains 0 && myVec contains 1
    %Code A
else
    %Code B
end
```

I checked that if you try for example `find(myVec==0)`and it returned the positions which fulfill the statement, it could be used as a boolean `if find(myVec==0)` but then I tried `if (find(myVec==0) && find(myVec==1))` and The following error is shown `Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.`

Thank you everyone.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: @excaza I tried to explain some more.

Comment: `find` returns an empty vector if there's nothing there, you need the `isempty` function and maybe the `not` function

Comment: @Trogdor That worked, thank you dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if sum(myVec==1) && sum(myVec==0)
    %Code A
else
    %Code B
end

% sum(myVec==1) counts the number of ones in myVec 
% sum(myVec==0) counts the number of zeros in myVec
% if myVec is a matrix with more than one rows and columns, use myVec(:) instead
```

Comment: `any(myVec == 1) && any(myVec == 0)` might work faster, plus it clearly shows the intent of the code

Comment: @SomeGuy Yes it will. +1.

Comment: @SomeGuy agreed!   